# Group by when case when

Tags: t-sql, case

I have a Table with an "Organization" column and a more specific "Units" column. I would like a count on the organization however if the organization = "ORG-4" then it should be grouped by a substring(unit,1,3).

My attempt look like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
  WHEN agency = 'ORG-4' THEN substring(unit, 1,3)  
  ELSE agency 
  END  as 'agency1', count(*)
 FROM km_agency Group by agency, substring(unit, 1,3)
```

Here is my try in the db-fiddle , i hope this helps:

https://dbfiddle.uk/E_x_0aBW

So the end result should look something like this.

| Agency1 | count |
| --- | --- |
| ORG-1 | 21 |
| ORG-2 | 16 |
| ORG-3 | 85 |
| NOR | 8 |
| SOU | 6 |

I've already tried various things with case-when, but if I enter the substring(unit,1,3) in the group by clause, then I "logically" get that for all non-"ORG-4" units as well.

Comment: You need to repeat the expression in your `GROUP BY`; you can't group on an alias defined in the `SELECT`, as it hasn't been processed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by the calculated expression.

To avoid repeating it you can put it into a `CROSS APPLY` and then reference that in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZA37C04s))

```
SELECT agency1,
       count(*)
FROM   km_agency
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN agency = 'ORG-4' THEN substring(unit, 1, 3)
                             ELSE agency
                           END) ca(agency1)
GROUP  BY agency1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks very much, can u explain  what " ca(agency1)" this does ? I thought cross apply where just used for functions paramters.It seems I still have a lot to learn here

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is often used to call table valued functions with correlated parameters but can also contain arbitrary select statements (correlated or not correlated) - in this case the `SELECT` statement uses the SQL Server `SELECT` syntax without a `FROM` clause to just calculate an expression based on the correlated columns from the outer scope.  The table alias for that table expression is `ca` and the column alias for the single column `agency1`. You can also use `VALUES`  here as an alternative. https://dbfiddle.uk/R_vqjyFp